# Horizontal center (dynamic width) tooltip

Tags: html, css, dynamic, width, center

How would one horizontal center a tooltip, where the width of the tooltip is dynamic (due to the text and white-space: nowrap).

**HTML**

```
<div class="example">
    <a class="label" href="#">This is a link</a>
    <div class="tooltip">
        <p><strong>Please center me</strong></p>
        <p>Dolor sit amet this is a very long text that shall not break</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.example {
    position: relative;
    margin: 200px 0 0 200px;
}
    .example .label {
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        background: blue;
        color: white;
    }
    .example .tooltip {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 45px;

        background: green;

        text-align: center;

        opacity: 0.75;

        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .example .label:hover + .tooltip {
        opacity: 1.0;
    }
    .example .tooltip:after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -10px;
        border-top: 10px solid green;
        border-left: 10px solid transparent;
        border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    }
```

**Example** http://jsfiddle.net/dwLgLogb/2/

Comment: what do you want centered, and with respect to what?

Comment: assuming the width of `.label` does not change, you could use `left: calc(-50% + 20px);` [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/dwLgLogb/3/)

Comment: @M.Doye that does not really work, try making the tooltip's text longer

Comment: @jmarkmurphy the tooltip should be centered relative to the 'button/label'. The arrow should be aligned.